# Fujitsu B6220 laptop, sometimes my desktop freezes upon resume from standby

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, laptop, freeze, gui

I was looking at my account and I noticed that this is still unresolved...  The site says to clarify the question explaining how it is different from the duplicate.  This is not a duplicate of the other questions because I want to find what is wrong.  The so-called duplicates say what to do After your GUI freezes, but they do NOT show a fix to stop it from happening in the first place. I want to stop it from happening in the first place.  Furthermore I think this problem has something to do with the laptop in question (Fujitsu Lifebook B6220).  Which also means it's not a duplicate.  I don't understand how this got misinterpreted as a duplicate.  Is it too much to ask that people don't be so quick to mark a question as a duplicate...

I have since reinstalled 12.04 and the problem still persists.  This is still a problem I am having so any ideas would be much appreciated.

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Fujitsu Lifebook B6220 laptop just before 12.04 was released.  I cannot remember if I had this issue with Ubuntu 11.10 as I updated the install to 12.04 about a week after 12.04 came out.

My problem is that sometimes upon resume from Standby my Desktop is frozen.  The keyboard, touch pad, and touchscreen work, but there is no response from the desktop.  I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and log in and then from there I just reboot the computer.  This happens about 50% of the time when I resume from standby but I have not noticed a distinct pattern.

I have thought about reinstalling 12.04, since I upgraded 11.10 to 12.04 instead of a fresh install.  But I have customized my laptop a lot and I would prefer to avoid reinstalling it, I'm not even sure if that would fix it.

Anyone have a idea what might be the problem? If I should submit this as a bug, could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Here are the specs: 1.33 GHz core solo, 2 gigs of ram, 32gb ssd,Intel® 945GM chipset, 128 mb integrated Intel graphics, 32-bit

Comment: I tried "unity --reset" to reset the interface and it still does does the same thing even with all the default settings.  Again the Possible Duplicate is not at all like my question and this question should not be closed.